# Como comparar o caminho de CSS de um elemento usando JS?

Tags: javascript

Não sei se "caminho" é a melhor definição. Mas, usando o `QuerySelector` é possível obter um elemento especificando um "caminho", como por exemplo:

```
main section.sobre .view-more
```

---

Mas, como posso fazer o oposto?

Se eu tiver um elemento, como `<button class="view-more">`, como posso fazer para verificar se ele é o `main section.sobre .view-more`?

A única forma que encontrei seria fazer um `QuerySelector` e então comparar este elemento com o elemento atual:

```js
window.document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  [].forEach.call(window.document.querySelectorAll("main section.sobre .view-more"), function(el) {
    if (el == e.target) {
      window.console.log("Isso é o main section.sobre .view-more");
    }
  });

}, true);
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <main>
    <section class="sobre">
      <button class="view-less">View Less</button>
      <button class="view-close">View Less</button>

      <button class="view-more">View More</button>
      <button class="view-more">View More</button>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

O problema é se for buscar por vários "caminhos" terá que executar vários `querySelectorAll`. Isso é, se quiser saber se o elemento é  `main .a`,  `main  .b`,  `main .c`, `main .d`, teria que fazer um `querySelectorAll` para cad um, então comparar. Isso ainda piora se houverem múltiplos elementos com o mesmo "caminho",  como o caso acima, já que terá que iterar pelo próprio `querySelectorAll`.

Isso funciona, mas não me parece correto. Existe outra forma, mais eficiente e nativa, de atingir esse objetivo?

Comment: Tem algum caso prático de uso disso ? O que iria fazer diferente com base no pai ? Não seria caso de usar um seletor que inclua o pai também ?

Comment: Eu estou usando o GopherJS, então dificulta dar um uso prático, mas é similar ao exemplo. Por simplicidade é mais fácil adicionar um único EventListener em "cada section" e nele monitorar os elementos. Por exemplo, num site de página única, cada section recebe um listener. Isso permite que adicione e remova os elementos e continue com um único listener. Dai teria um `mapa map[caminho]Listener(e dom.Event)`, por página. Então bastaria fazer dentro do único EventListener um `if listen, ok := mapa[caminho(event)]; ok { listen(event) }`. Isso é usa o listenner do elemento, previamente definido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma função para isso, [`matchesSelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Sintaxe:

```
element.matchesSelector(selectorString)
```

Onde `element` é qualquer elemento HTML e `selectorString` é uma string que representa um seletor CSS válido. A função retorna um booleano, `true` caso o seletor CSS represente um possível caminho para o elemento, e `false` caso contrário

Muitos navegadores implementam essa função com o seu prefixo, por exemplo, o chrome possui o `webkitMatchesSelector`, você pode usar esse  polyfill que está na documentação da MDN:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches)
    Element.prototype.matches = 
        Element.prototype.matchesSelector || 
        Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
        Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
        Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector || 
        Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
        function(s) {
            var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                i = matches.length
            while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
            return i > -1            
        }
```

Exemplo de uso:

```js
if (!Element.prototype.matches)
    Element.prototype.matches = 
        Element.prototype.matchesSelector || 
        Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
        Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
        Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector || 
        Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
        function(s) {
            var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                i = matches.length
            while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
            return i > -1            
        }

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('main section.sobre .view-more'))
    console.log("Isso é o main section.sobre .view-more");
}, true);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <section class="sobre">
      <button class="view-less">View Less</button>
      <button class="view-close">View Less</button>

      <button class="view-more">View More</button>
      <button class="view-more">View More</button>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a propriedade `.parent` para ir subindo na árvore de componentes e buscar as classes e tags pais e assim montar sua consulta apenas uma única vez.

```
window.document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        let parent1 = e.target.parentElement;
        let parent2 = parent1.parentElement;
        if(!parent1 || !parent2) return;

        let tree = parent2.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ' ' + parent1.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '.' + parent1.className +  ' .' + e.target.className;

        console.log(tree == 'main section.sobre .view-more');

}, true);
```

Comment: Isso resolve mais ou menos. Se houver lacunas do "caminho" não funcionará, se for algo como "main .view-more", faltando o "section". Uma outro problema é se tiver o id ou o elemento, como `main button.view-more`. Em casos "gerais" isso não me parece funcionar.